# Remix + multiple Prisma Express.js monorepo

Tags: typescript, express, prisma, monorepo, remix.run

I have an NPM workspaces monorepo that has two packages, one is a Remix app and the other one is an ExpressJS backend. The Remix app and ExpressJS app doesn't share code* and communicate using fetch (normal fetch API calls since they run on different servers).

*I'm sharing the Prisma generated typescript types from the backend to the Remix app through node_modules by installing the Prisma Client on Remix, but I need to add another Express API with it's own Prisma model.

How can I share both Prisma generated types between the two backends and the Remix app?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I am running into the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extract the Prisma parts into another package within your monorepo. Then the Remix and Express packages can depend on the internal Prisma package for shared types.

https://github.com/alitnk/nestjs-prisma-monorepo shows an example of doing so, though it uses Nest.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need two different Express APIs with two different Prisma schemas, one for each. The Remix app will call both APIs and I need to use both Prisma clients.